# The 'myEvent' is not being set in the getPastEvents function of web3.js

Tags: web3js

I am using "web3" : "4.5.0"

I am trying to use the getPastEvents function in accordance with the official documentation of web3.js to view the emitted events for a specific event.

However, I keep encountering the "No overload matches this call" error consistently.

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(eventName: "allEvents" | "ALLEVENTS", returnFormat?: DataFormat | undefined): Promise<(string | EventLog)[]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"Transfer"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"allEvents" | "ALLEVENTS"'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(filter: Omit<Filter, "address">, returnFormat?: DataFormat | undefined): Promise<(string | EventLog)[]>', gave the following error.
    Type '"Transfer"' has no properties in common with type 'Omit<Filter, "address">'.
  Overload 3 of 4, '(eventName: "allEvents" | "ALLEVENTS", filter: Omit<Filter, "address">, returnFormat?: { readonly number: FMT_NUMBER.BIGINT; readonly bytes: FMT_BYTES.HEX; } | undefined): Promise<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"Transfer"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"allEvents" | "ALLEVENTS"'.
    502 |
    503 |   const getLogs = async() => {
  > 504 |     const events = await erc1400.getPastEvents('Transfer',{
        |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^
    505 |       fromBlock: 0, // 이벤트를 조회할 시작 블록 번호
    506 |       toBlock: 30, // 최신 블록 번호
    507 |     });
```

Here is my calling source code.

```
  const erc1400 = new web3.eth.Contract(ERC1400.abi,'0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512')

  const getLogs = async() => {
    const events = await erc1400.getPastEvents('Transfer',{
      fromBlock: 0, // 이벤트를 조회할 시작 블록 번호
      toBlock: 30, // 최신 블록 번호
    });
  
    // 조회된 이벤트를 출력합니다.
    events.forEach(async (event:any) => {
      //emit한 내역
      console.log(event.returnValues);
    });
  
  }
```

The official documentation states that setting "MyEvent" allows for the retrieval of specific events. However, based on the error message, it seems that only allEvents or ALLEVENTS can be set.
[image]

Is there an issue with my source code? Please help.